# Search is Not Returning An Entire Attribute Set of Products in Magento 1.13 EE (1.8 CE)

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch, enterprise-1.13

After upgrading to 1.13 EE (1.8 CE), an entire attribute set of products no longer shows up in search results. The products have visibility of 'Search' and the product page for this product works fine in both our 1.12 EE (1.7 CE) and 1.13 EE instances. The search works fine in 1.12 but fails entirely in 1.13.
The row is there in the catalogsearch_fulltext as seen here:

```
SELECT * FROM catalogsearch_fulltext WHERE data_index LIKE '%3402-757%';
+------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| product_id | store_id | data_index                                                          | fulltext_id |
+------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|    2443712 |        1 | ARCTICCAT-3402-757|Taxable Goods|Arctic Cat|Arctic Cat - 3402-757   |   139705308 |
|            |          | - V BELT, DRIVE||Authentic V BELT, DRIVE from Arctic Cat (Part#:    |             |
|            |          | 3402-757). UPC: 886224105147|Authentic V BELT, DRIVE from Arctic    |             |
|            |          | Cat (Part#: 3402-757). UPC: 886224105147|194.72|1                   |             |
+------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Did something change regarding search in 1.13 Is there something else I'm missing here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`PATCH_SUPEE-4937_EE_1.13.1.0_v1.sh` did the trick

```
__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__
diff --git app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Catalog/Category/Product/Refresh.php app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Catalog/Category/Product/Refresh.php
index ff9883a..452f1a5 100644
--- app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Catalog/Category/Product/Refresh.php
+++ app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Catalog/Category/Product/Refresh.php
@@ -554,13 +554,6 @@ class Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Catalog_Category_Product_Refresh
                     $this->_connection->getIfNullSql('cpss.value', 'cpsd.value') . ' = ?',
                     Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED
                 )
-                ->where(
-                    $this->_connection->getIfNullSql('cpvs.value', 'cpvd.value') . ' IN (?)',
-                    array(
-                        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
-                        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
-                    )
-                )
                 ->columns(
                     array(
                         'category_id'   => 'cc.entity_id',
@@ -698,13 +691,6 @@ class Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Catalog_Category_Product_Refresh
                     Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED
                 )
                 ->where(
-                    $this->_connection->getIfNullSql('cpvs.value', 'cpvd.value') . ' IN (?)',
-                    array(
-                        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
-                        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
-                    )
-                )
-                ->where(
                     $this->_connection->getIfNullSql('ccas.value', 'ccad.value') . ' = ?',
                     1
                 )
@@ -805,13 +791,6 @@ class Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Catalog_Category_Product_Refresh
                     $this->_connection->getIfNullSql('cpss.value', 'cpsd.value') . ' = ?',
                     Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED
                 )
-                ->where(
-                    $this->_connection->getIfNullSql('cpvs.value', 'cpvd.value') . ' IN (?)',
-                    array(
-                        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
-                        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
-                    )
-                )
                 ->group('cp.entity_id')
                 ->columns(
                     array(
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you did? And how it has solved the problem?

Comment: added relevant patchfile